# How should I plan for a QA job where I work at home, part time?

Tags: work-place

Working from home has many advantages, no commute time, no relocation and a lot of other benefits.

As an alternative I think I need a future job for me mainly to have the following characteristics:

- working at home 90+% of the time
- part-time (4 to 6 hours/day)

In exchange I would give the following:

- smaller income / hour;
- availability on saturday (up to 4 hours)

What strategy should I adopt for this goal on a 1 to 3 years timespan to achieve this goal?

But first I want to ask if there are people working from home in QA, or if there is a market for this kind of job. Is the above goal feasible and is anyone who has a first hand experience working as a QA from home ?

Comment: You want a job where you work 4-6 hours per week?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere 4-6 per day I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What strategy should I adopt for this goal on a 1 to 3 years timespan
>   to achieve this goal?

I think you have several ways to achieve this goal:

1. Work as a contractor. I have hired contractors in the past that were permitted to work part-time. And on one occasion, with a contractor who was very experienced, very familiar and very trustworthy, she was permitted to work from home much of the time.
2. Seek out a company who is hiring part-time folks and has a culture allowing work from home. My current company has some work-from-home folks, and some part-time folks. I don't know if there are any who do both at the same time, but I suspect it must be happening (although not in my locale).
3. Do piece work - either on your own, or in conjunction with something like uTest.

> But first I want to ask if there are people working from home in QA,
>   or if there is a market for this kind of job. Is the above goal
>   feasible and is anyone who has a first hand experience working as a QA
>   from home ?

Yes, there are people working from home in QA.

Yes, there is a market, although it is clearly more limited than the market for traditional workers.

Yes, the goal is feasible. You have to be very good at QA, very trustworthy, and may have to search a while to find the right circumstances.

Good luck!