# Are there any part time jobs related to QA?

Tags: work-place

I am currently working as full time QA but seeking opportunity in part time job in QA.
I can spend 4/5 hour per week. please suggest any.

Comment: 4/5 hours per week or day?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I plan for a QA job where I work at home, part time?](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7022/how-should-i-plan-for-a-qa-job-where-i-work-at-home-part-time)

Comment: This is not a job site.

Comment: It appears the writer is looking for work.

Comment: @Edu, or maybe 4/5 hour per week, i.e. 48 min per week? I don't think this was the intention. I think the author ment 4/5 of the normal work time per week, i.e. roughly 4 of 5 business days in a week.

Answer (score 5):

> Are there any part time jobs related to QA?

Certainly. There are many folks working in QA as part-timers.

Some of them are part-time employees, others are contractors working less than full-time hours.

> I can spend 4/5 hour per week.

4 or 5 hours is a pretty small amount for a useful QA role.

I have never hired anyone to work less than a few days per week. And I don't know of anyone who has ever worked in a position for that few number of hours.

There are sites like uTest (and others) where you can be paid by the bug you find, and work as many or as few hours as you choose. They don't seem like very lucrative jobs, but it might be just what you are looking for.